# Compute distances between points and lines by rows

Tags: r, distance

I would like to calculate distances between points and lines displayed in each row of my dataset.
Here below a small example of the data I have

```r
  point_id point_lat point_lon                       geometry line_id
1    25417   47.2085   6.23435 LINESTRING (5.71922 47.01, ...    1203
2    21475   47.0499   5.21145 LINESTRING (5.13693 46.9399...    1120

dput(data)

structure(list(point_id = c("25417", "21475"), point_lat = c(47.2084948390554, 
47.049888920732), point_lon = c(6.23434636370335, 5.21144989212184
), geometry = structure(list(structure(c(5.7192239291661, 5.72408115442851, 
47.0100084570507, 47.0055943850847), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(5.13693475951681, 5.14588443111801, 
46.9399237940937, 46.9393947420422), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_LINESTRING", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 5.13693475951681, 
ymin = 46.9393947420422, xmax = 5.72408115442851, ymax = 47.0100084570507
), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "EPSG:4326", 
    wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    ENSEMBLE[\"World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble\",\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)\"],\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Horizontal component of 3D system.\"],\n        AREA[\"World.\"],\n        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L), 
    line_id = c(1203L, 1120L)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to compute the distance between the points its corresponding line. So the distance between point 25417 and line 1203 and the distance between 21475 and line 1120.

Thank you for your help

Comment: `object 'A' not found` ... do you mean `id_line=c("A","B")` or do you have objects named `A` and `B` that you forgot to share?

Comment: It looks like you _want_ to have list-columns here, but you don't, they're just strings. Is your real data also strings-not-real-list-columns, or are you working with `sf` data, or is something going on here?

Comment: Next question ... I'm inferring that you want the distance between the point defined by `long_points`/`lat_points` with each line-segment defined within `line_geometry`. Are you looking for a closest-distance between the point and the segment? Do you know how to calculate that in general? Are you using packages `sf` or `geosphere`? I'm having a difficult time finding how `5` and `10` are accurate distances for the data as given.

Comment: I just want to calculate the distance between point 1 and line A,  and point 2 and line B. Sorry for that I should have specify it is not the accurate distance, I wrote them randomly

Comment: I edited the post, and the lines coordinates are actually in a sfc_LINESTRING form in my data

Comment: There it is ... please share data like that using `dput(.)`. I also recommend tagging [tag:sf], since that brings in a full ecosystem of tools and utilities that base R takes a bit more work to do. Bottom line ... the distances I'm seeing between the point and each point of the line are on the order of 13.078 to 13.359 kilometers (row 1), not sure how you get 5 out of that.

Comment: Okay thank you for all the advice! I Edited my post taking them into account.

Comment: see `?sf::geos_measures` for usage of `sf::st_distance`.

Comment: Related? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/360675/how-to-calculate-the-distance-of-points-to-line-in-r and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243994/how-to-calculate-distance-from-point-to-linestring-in-r-using-sf-library-and-g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a somewhat uncommon structure as it comes with a `geometry` / sfc column but `sf` class attribute is not set or is intentionally removed (i.e. `sf` methods can't be used on a frame itself)

We could go with something like this while keeping the result as `data.frame`:

- generate `sf` points object from point coordinates, assume coordinates are in WGS84 (`y` argument)
- find element-wise distance between lines in `geometry` column (`x` argument) and generated `sf` object (`y`)

```r
library(sf)
data$dist_m <- st_distance(x = data$geometry, 
                           y = st_as_sf(data, coords = c("point_lon", "point_lat"), crs = "WGS84"),
                           by_element = TRUE)
data
#>   point_id point_lat point_lon                       geometry line_id
#> 1    25417  47.20849  6.234346 LINESTRING (5.719224 47.010...    1203
#> 2    21475  47.04989  5.211450 LINESTRING (5.136935 46.939...    1120
#>         dist_m
#> 1 44725.65 [m]
#> 2 13254.55 [m]
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>